# Spring boot JPA data : no transaction is in progress exception for Service layer methods

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-transactions

the problem is I can't manage to get working simple project with
`@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)` and service layer method annotated with `@Transactional`. I need to run business logic on a locked entity/DB row. When I run the application it throws an error on the session layer

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: no transaction is in progress; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
```

`Main class`

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class BackendApplication {

    private final BackendConfiguration configuration;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BackendApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

`SessionService`

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class SessionService {

    final private SessionRepository sessionRepository;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
    Session readAndUpdateSession(String sessionId, Function<Session, Session> sessionPreUpdateHandler, String threadName) {
        Optional<SessionEntity> forUpdate = sessionRepository.getBySessionId(sessionId);
        Session session = new Session(forUpdate.map(SessionEntity::getSessionId).orElse(null), false);

        Session updatedSession = sessionPreUpdateHandler.apply(session);

        sessionRepository.save(forUpdate.orElse(null));

        log.info(" thread [{}] updated session", threadName);

        return updatedSession;
    }
}
```

`SessionRepository`

```
@Repository
public interface SessionRepository extends JpaRepository<SessionEntity, String> {

    @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    Optional<SessionEntity> getBySessionId(String id);

}
```

and `CommandLineRunner` to test

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class CommandLineRunner implements org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner {

    private final SessionRepository sessionRepository;
    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        sessionRepository.save(new SessionEntity().setSessionId("7d010e0a-cf6e-492c-9db4-690a96b4e345"));

        log.info("" + sessionRepository.findForUpdate("7d010e0a-cf6e-492c-9db4-690a96b4e345").orElse(null));

        new Thread(() -> applicationContext.getBean(SessionService.class).readAndUpdateSession("7d010e0a-cf6e-492c-9db4-690a96b4e345", session -> {

            log.info("first thread reading and updating doing business ");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            log.info("first thread return session back ");
            return session;
        }, "first")).start();

        new Thread(() -> applicationContext.getBean(SessionService.class).readAndUpdateSession("7d010e0a-cf6e-492c-9db4-690a96b4e345", session -> {

            log.info("second thread reading and updating but first is not accomplished");

            log.info("second thread return session back ");
            return session;

        }, "second")).start();

    }
}
```

and last but not least `application.yml`

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/backend
    hikari:
      username: backend
      password: backend
      driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
      connection-timeout: 1000
      connection-test-query: SELECT 1
      maximum-pool-size: 32
    sql-script-encoding: UTF-8
  cache:
    type: jcache
  jpa:
    generate-ddl: false
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

I applied suggestions on the internet but didn't figure out how can I tackle this problem,

Comment: okay, for me the solution was: to take out `@EnableTransactionManagement` from the Main class and disable `auto-commit ` for `hikari`

Comment: Hey, how that's youre solutions worked? doesnt supposed  to be that `@EnableTransactionManagement` is required?

Comment: Hey, yes by the time I tested it worked fine